# Even Vertical Button Spacing Android

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I get this column to fill the screen evenly in a vertical direction.  Or put another way I have 5 buttons and I want them evenly vertically spaced in this vertical column.  See my pic for clarity of what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Layout]

The XML for the left column I have so far is this, but the buttons are grouped together and I can move the group to the top middle or bottom but what I really want is them to simply be spaced evenly vertically so they display correctly on multiple devices:

```
<GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/m1_btn_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/m1_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/pause" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/m2_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/pause" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/m3_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/pause" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/m4_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/pause" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/m5_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/pause" />
    </GridLayout>
```

I have tried this with LinearLayout too but cannot achieve what I am after.  My XML above gives me this:

[image: Layout1]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to acheive the design as you asked in the question. I've showed you one way which can be achieved through `TableLayout`. Use of `android:weightSum` and `android:layout_weight`inside `LinearLayout` helps out to achieve the same.

The same can be achieved through `GridLayout`. Just try to play with different `View` which can make it possible to deploy the same as you asked for.

Achieved  through `TableLayout` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TableLayout 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="5"

        >

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <Button 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="Button1"
                />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <Button 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="Button1"
                />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <Button 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="Button1"
                />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <Button 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="Button1"
                />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
            <Button 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:text="Button1"
                />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="MediaPlayer" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer and works a charm.  Thanks for your expert advice.  I much appreciate it. :)